# Embedd a matplotlib graph in tkinter canvas widget class

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I try to create a small tkinter GUI which uses classes, as seen on this [site/youtube](https://pythonprogramming.net/tkinter-depth-tutorial-making-actual-program/) channel.

My program, through a tk.Menu, will load a CSV file and print a graph in the interior of a canvas. If I load an other file the graph will be cleared and recreated with 2 lines. If adding a new file will increase the number of lines in the graph, and so on. I've already have a program which does this but doesn't use classes. Bellow is the output of the program which uses functions only.
[Using functions only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6tFy.png)

Using the classes gives me an distinct window, which I want to be embedded in the canvas.
[Using classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6fHw.png)

I think the solution is simple but I don't see it by myself.

My code is bellow:

```py
f = Figure()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self,  text = "Start Page", font = SMALL_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx = 10)
        btn_About = ttk.Button(self, text="About!",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AboutPage))
        btn_About.place(relx = 1.0, rely = 0.0, anchor=NE)

        #Graph Canvas --> where the graph will show + navigation toolbar
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

The function for showing the graph:

```py
def PlotGraph():
    global count
    plt.clf()

    # values taken every time a csv file is loaded
    TakeValues()    #x values are the same, y values are changing

    # change plot axis scale using numpy arange method
    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, max(xdata)))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(minLSB_err, maxLSB_err))

    if count != 0:
        for i in range(count + 1):
            label = filename_dict[i]
            plt.plot(xdata, ydata[i], label=label[:-4], lw=2)
    else:
        label = filename_dict[0]
        plt.plot(xdata, ydata, label=label[:-4], lw=2)


    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.02, 1, .102), loc=3,
             ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
    plt.title("Total Error")
    plt.xlabel("Voltage Applied [V]")
    plt.ylabel("LSB deviation")

    plt.tight_layout()

    count = count + 1
    plt.draw()
    try:
        plt.show()
    except (AttributeError) as e:
        print("Error occured:",e)
```

[UPDATE]
Where the PlotGraph() must be placed and from where should I call it?
Now it's like this:

```py
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=PlotGraph)    #Open CSV files
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `Figure` instead of `pyplot` if you want to embed your graph to `tkinter`. See [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) for a sample.

Comment: Indeed using Figure and a subplot is working. But now the graph lines appears only when I resize the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Henry Yik specifies using a Figure works. The StartPage class remains the same but I've added the bellow code:

```
f = Figure()
a = f.add_subplot(111)
```

also changed the PlotGraph() function like this:

```py
def PlotGraph():
    global count
    # values taken every time a csv   file is loaded
    TakeValues()  # x values are the same, y values are changing

    a.clear()

    # change plot axis scale using numpy arange method
    a.set_xticks(np.arange(0, max(xdata)))
    a.set_yticks(np.arange(minLSB_err, maxLSB_err))

    if count != 0:
        for i in range(count + 1):
            label = filename_dict[i]
            a.plot(xdata, ydata[i], label=label[:-4], lw=2)
    else:
        label = filename_dict[0]
        a.plot(xdata, ydata, label=label[:-4], lw=2)


    a.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.02, 1, .102), loc=3,
             ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
    a.set_title("Total Error")
    a.set_xlabel("Voltage Applied [V]")
    a.set_ylabel("LSB deviation")

    count = count + 1

    return f
```

The PlotGraph() is not included in any class.